# Can one create an iTerm / Terminal (MacOSX) Secure session?

Tags: command-line, security, iterm

I use iTerm for doing things such as creating passwords by selecting random words from `/usr/dict`.  I prefix the commands with a space so they aren't saved in the shell history.  I discovered to my horror that iTerm2 keeps recent paste, commands and other history.  See `Session > Open Paste / command / ...`.  Its all there in plain text sqlite db file.

I found that these are saved to `~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/` and I simply deleted these files.  However this is not a very good solution since everything is deleted and has to be done every time.

My questions are - is this data saved anywhere else and is there a way to create secure sessions so this doesn't happen?

Comment: Just use X11.app’s xterm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, it seems that Terminal (MacOSX Default app) doesn't save such data anywhere (at least under `~/Library/Application\ Support/`)?  So my answer is how to have secure sessions (generally).  But it doesn't answer if iTerm2 does this anywhere else nor how to create 'secure sessions' (one where the commands aren't saved) using it.

This is my answer though I welcome anything better.